# Published Object Not Working - Combine Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, combine

Anyone who understands please help me, I want to retrieve data from Firestore and it wants to be read in realtime whenever there is a change from the database, so I use addSnapshotListener to read it, it works every time there is a change from Firestore, but it's still in object form NewsResponse. Because the final result I want to change to a NewsDomainModel form, then I continue the results from NewsResponse to _mapper.transformerResponseToDomain to be converted into NewsDomainModel, but every latest data generated using addSnapshotListener is not updated to the _mapper.transformerResponseToDomain, _mapper only reads 1 time the data sent only.

GetNewsRepository

```
import SwiftUI
import Core
import Combine

public class GetNewsRepository<
  NewsLocaleDataSource: LocaleDataSource,
  RemoteDataSource: DataSource,
  Transformer: Mapper>: ObservableObject, Repository
where
  NewsLocaleDataSource.Request == String,
  NewsLocaleDataSource.Response == NewsModuleEntity,
  RemoteDataSource.Request == String,
  RemoteDataSource.Response == [NewsResponse],
  Transformer.Request == String,
  Transformer.Response == [NewsResponse],
  Transformer.Entity == [NewsModuleEntity],
  Transformer.Domain == [NewsDomainModel] {
  
  public typealias Request = String
  @Published public var Response: [NewsDomainModel] = [NewsDomainModel]()
  
  private let _localeDataSource: NewsLocaleDataSource
  @Published public var _remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource
  @Published public var _mapper: Transformer
  
  public init(
    localeDataSource: NewsLocaleDataSource,
    remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource,
    mapper: Transformer) {
    _localeDataSource = localeDataSource
    _remoteDataSource = remoteDataSource
    _mapper = mapper
  }
  
  public func execute(request: String?) -> AnyPublisher<[NewsDomainModel], Error> {
    return self._remoteDataSource.execute(request: request)
      .map { self._mapper.transformerResponseToDomain(response: $0) }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

GetNewsRemoteDataSource

```
import Core
import Combine
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Foundation

public class GetNewsRemoteDataSource: ObservableObject, DataSource {
  
  public typealias Request = String
  @Published public var Response: [NewsResponse] = [NewsResponse]()
  private let _endPoint: String
  
  public init(endPoint: String) {
    _endPoint = endPoint
  }
  
  public func execute(request: String?) -> AnyPublisher<[NewsResponse], Error> {
    return Future<[NewsResponse], Error> { completion in
      let ref = Firestore.firestore()
      
      ref.collection("news").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
          print("Document not found")
          return
        }
        
        let dataJson = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
          try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: NewsResponse.self)
        } // THIS DATA WILL BE AUTOMATIC UPDATE IF DATA FROM FIRESTORE UPDATED
        
        completion(.success(dataJson))
      }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

NewsTransformer

```
import Core
import Combine

public class NewsTransformer<NewsMapper: Mapper>: ObservableObject, Mapper
where
  NewsMapper.Request == String,
  NewsMapper.Response == NewsResponse,
  NewsMapper.Entity == NewsModuleEntity,
  NewsMapper.Domain == NewsDomainModel {
  
  @Published public var Request = String()
  @Published public var Response = [NewsResponse]()
  @Published public var Entity = [NewsModuleEntity]()
  @Published public var Domain = [NewsDomainModel]()
  
  private let _newsMapper: NewsMapper
  
  public init(newsMapper: NewsMapper) {
    _newsMapper = newsMapper
  }
  
  public func transformerResponseToEntity(request: String?, response: [NewsResponse]) -> [NewsModuleEntity] {
    return response.map { result in
      _newsMapper.transformerResponseToEntity(request: request, response: result)
    }
  }
  
  public func transformerResponseToDomain(response: [NewsResponse]) -> [NewsDomainModel] {
    print("\(response) DATA RESPONSE") // NOT UPDATING
    return response.map { results in
      _newsMapper.transformerResponseToDomain(response: results)
    }
  }
  
  public func transformerEntityToDomain(entity: [NewsModuleEntity]) -> [NewsDomainModel] {
    return entity.map { result in
      _newsMapper.transformerEntityToDomain(entity: result)
    }
  }
  
  public func transformerDomainToEntities(domain: [NewsDomainModel]) -> [NewsModuleEntity] {
    return domain.map { result in
      _newsMapper.transformerDomainToEntities(domain: result)
    }
  }
}
```

The sequence of images above is GetNewsRepository (Repository), GetNewsRemoteDataSource (Get Data From Firebase), NewsTransformer (Transform from NewsResponse to NewsDomainModel)

Sorry if the title I ask is wrong.

Comment: Please post code, not images of code, which isn't copy/pastable, searchable, doesn't work on screen readers, etc.

Comment: Ok i've updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Future` in `GetNewsRemoteDataSource` completes. Once a publisher has completed it won't send any further values. Instead of using a `Future`, return a `PassthroughSubject`. And use the .send method to pass values through the publisher.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/passthroughsubject

Comment: thanks for the advice you give, this is working well

Comment: No problem, if it works then mark it as an answer :-)